# Prove that $G^{op} \cong G$ when $G^{op}$ is the opposite group of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $G = (G,\times)$ be a group, and $G^{op} = (G,o), a \ o \ b = b \times a$ be it's opposite group.

I need to prove that there is a group isomorphism $f: G \to G^{op}$
Obviously, $id_G: G \to G$ is a bijection, but it's a group homomorphism if and only if $G$ is commutative.

Comment: Try $g\mapsto g^{-1}$.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman Great, it works! $f(a \ o \ b) = (a \ o \ b)^{-1} = b^{-1} \ o \ a^{-1} = a^{-1} \times b^{-1} = f(a) \times f(b)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How might one come up with $g \mapsto g^{-1}$?

It is clear that $g g^{-1}$ must be mapped to $g^{-1} g$ (by definition of the opposite group "reversing multiplication"). Note that $\phi(g g^{-1}) = \phi(g) \phi(g^{-1}) = \phi(g) \phi(g)^{-1}$, which is expected to be $g^{-1} g$. That suggests $\phi: g \mapsto g^{-1}$.

(Incidentally, this is an instance of a *much* more general phenomenon: that of duality in category theory.)