# Show that $H$ is a group, and that it is isomorphic to $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Let $G$ be any group. Let $H$ consist of the same set of elements as $G$, but with
> a new operation given by $a ∗ b = ba$, for all $a$ and $b$. Show that $H$ is a group, and
> that it is isomorphic to $G$.

I am having trouble proving what is being asked of me. First, I have no information about how the operation is in $G$. I suppose I could define the operation in $G$ as is usually done for group definition, this is if $a, b \in G$, then its product is $ab$. Based on that, $H$ with the new operation would be a group as well, since they have the same elements. The truth seems like nonsense to me but I can't think of anything else.

Also I have tried to establish an isomorphism and let the rest follow from this fact, but so far it has been unsuccessful. Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: You can show this directly from the axioms. For example can you see why $H$ is closed under $*$ using the given definition for $*$ in terms of the group operation for $G$?

Comment: It isn't the same group, because the operation is different.  A group comprises a set of elements *and* a binary operation.

Comment: As a hint, try mapping elements  $a$ in the group to $a^{-1}$.

Comment: hint: inversion map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $G^{op} \cong G$ when $G^{op}$ is the opposite group of G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808840/prove-that-gop-cong-g-when-gop-is-the-opposite-group-of-g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check the axioms of group for $H$. For instance if $e$ is the neutral element of $G$ then so is for $H$ since $e * g = ge=g$ and if $g^{-1}$ is the inverse of $g$ in $G$ then so is it in $H$ since $g * g^{-1}= g^{-1} g =e$.

For the isomorphism define $f: G \to H$, $f(g):= g^{-1}$. It is a group homomorphism since $$f(ab)=(ab)^{-1}= b^{-1}a^{-1} = f(b)f(a)= f(a)*f(b).$$ Its inverse $f^{-1}: H \to G$ is defined exactly in the same way, $f^{-1}(g):=g^{-1}$, and it is indeed the inverse of $f$ since $(g^{-1})^{-1}=g$.